# Insert into a mysql table with columns of another table

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

What i am trying to do looks like the following

```
insert into user_audit 
( SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME='user' and TABLE_SCHEMA = database() )
VAlUES ( SELECT * FROM `user` where id = NEW.id  )
```

Insert into user_audit the column name of user table and the values of user table

Thanks for helping

Comment: what do you want to do.. using "New" seems like you are working with trigger..

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following Dynamic SQL:

It might help

```
declare @insertquery nvarchar(1000)
Declare @ColumnNames varchar(2000)
select @ColumnNames = COALESCE(@ColumnNames + ', ', '') + COLUMN_NAME
from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where 
    TABLE_NAME='user' and TABLE_SCHEMA = database();

set @insertquery = N'insert into user_audit(' + @ColumnNames + ') SELECT * FROM `user` where id = NEW.id;

sp_executesql @insertquery
```

Comment: This might be a same question as this one :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885244/selecting-column-name-dynamically-in-an-insert-query