# Dynamic SQL query to insert data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have gone through various post here on SO, but I am still not able to write a working code using dynamic SQL.

I generally prefer EF/ dapper (any other ORM) for my CRUD operations but in this case I can't.

What I am trying to achieve is allowing the user to select the table on which he/she wants to perform a CRUD operation. I am anticipating there would be ~10-15 table on which these operations can be performed, but the number can vary. Since I wouldn't know on which table the user wants to perform the operation before hand I thought I can write a dynamic query for this functionality.(open for other options as well)

This is what I have but it does work.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_insert 
    @TABLENAME NVARCHAR(30),
    @COLUMNNAME NVARCHAR(MAX),
   -- NEED TO HAVE A VARIABLE FOR INPUT DATA    
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS(SELECT @TABLENAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
              WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TABLENAME)
        SELECT @ColumnName = COALESCE(@ColumnName + ', ', '') + COLUMN_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TABLENAME

    DECLARE @SqlStatement nvarchar(max);
    SET @SqlStatement = N'INSERT INTO '+ @TABLENAME+'('+@COLUMNNAME+ ') VALUES (---NOT SURE HOW TO PASS VALUES---)'
      
    EXEC (@SqlStatement);
    PRINT @SQLSTATEMENT
END
```

The problem with the above code is

1. I am not sure how to pass the data
2. The columns are getting repeated, something like

   ```
    INSERT INTO testtable1(MyProperty1, MyProperty2, MyProperty3, MyProperty4, MyProperty5, MyProperty1, MyProperty2, MyProperty3, MyProperty4, MyProperty5)
   ```

   if I pass my columns as parameter

Any help how be highly appreciated ...cheers !

These are the links I have already looked into :
[selecting-column-name-dynamically-in-an-insert-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885244/selecting-column-name-dynamically-in-an-insert-query)
[t-sql-dynamic-query](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1069695/How-to-write-a-dynamic-query-for-insert-statement)
[How-to-write-a-dynamic-query-for-insert-statement](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1069695/How-to-write-a-dynamic-query-for-insert-statement)

**Edit**: Just to avoid any confusion, the table I am referring to is the only table in the entire DB(its just a POC to check whether this approach would work or not). The implementation(*not my design*) is like this.

I'll have a list of tables in a dropdown, the user would select the table, and on the basis of the selected table the data would be fetched and displayed in a grid on the UI. The user can then either edit(update), insert(add new record) or delete (soft delete) a record pertaining to that table.
I am open for other suggestions as well but this list (dropdown) is configurable i.e. new tables can be added at run time, so I can only write SPs for the table I know in advance. I agree its not a good design but this what I have to do with. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Honestly, however, this has the strong smell of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). If you don't know what table you're doing to be inserting into, getting a parameter to accept said data is basically impossible. If you *need* a Procedure to handle the `INSERT` statements, then have 1 per table, and the application will have relevant screens for the different tables, and call the appropriate procedure. You're trying to go a rabbit hole you really shouldn't be trying to.

Comment: Use Distinct to remove duplicate columns.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-examples-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: There *shouldn't* be duplicate columns in that query though, @jdweng, not unless the OP has objects with the same name on different schemas; but then if so then the schema name should also be a parameter in the query, as they could easily have different definitions too.

Comment: @Larnu : The OP is getting duplicates because the same column names are in more than one table.

Comment: @jdweng it's impossible for a table to have 2 columns with the same name. The clause `where TABLE_NAME=@TABLENAME` will mean that the columns only tables with the name of that in `@TABLENAME` will be returned. If they are getting 2 columns with the same name, that means that they have multiple tables with the same name (thus on different schemas).

Comment: The most likely source of duplication is that OP is passing a CSV string of column names in that 2nd parameter and then appending those same (presumably) names to the parameter using that old-style string aggregation method - causing the duplication. The logic current in place is in need of serious design work first and foremost.

Comment: @Larnu : Read my response again.  I did not say 2 columns in same table.

Comment: And I'm saying check the `WHERE` again, @jdweng  and my initial comment to you. If you can, however, create a 2 tables, with different names (and on the same schema) that are both returned in the query `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName;` then I would actually be very interested to see that.

Comment: This is a terrible idea.  You (or your replacement) will regret this approach.  You must know the data you'll use at compile time so there is no need for dynamic SQL generated from the database.  Also, simply adding a column to the table later will break your code completely.  If you continue with this, your code will be overly complex, hard to maintain and easily broken.  KEEP IT SIMPLE

Comment: @Larnu :The OP needs to clear the output table before running the stored procedure.  If the stored procedure is run multiple times duplicates get added.

Comment: Variables declared within a Procedure don't persist after a Procedure has completed, @jdweng .